# Is there a way to push tarred repository to dockerhub without loading on local

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub

I have a tarred docker repository created by using docker save.

I want to push this tar to a registry, say dockerhub. Is there a way we can do that without loading on local docker?

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is not possible as `docker push` command will look for a local image or a repository.
You will have to load your image first from tar file, the push it to your registry.

```
docker load --input repo.tar
docker image tag myrepo registry-host:5000/myrepo/myrepo:v1
docker image push registry-host:5000/myrepo/myrepo:v1
```